# Create new arrays from existing arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have arrays:

```
const array_one = ["a", "b", "c"];

const array_two = ["d", "e"];

const array_Three = ["f", "g", "h"]
```

more arrays...

After processing, return results:

```
[{"exp1":"a","exp2":"d","exp3":"f",},{"exp4":"a","exp5":"e","exp6":"g",},{"exp7":"a","exp8":"e","exp9":"h",},{"exp10":"b","exp11":"d","exp12":"f",}...,{"exp44":"c","exp45":"e","exp46":"h",}]
```

---

I give a simpler example than what I encountered, I would like to add.

```
const array = [{values: ["a, "b", "c"]}, {values: ["d, "e", "f"]}, {values: ["g, "h", "i"]}...];
```

The number of objects in the array is dynamic, Currently I need to check the array of how many objects, and repeat under the conditions ..., I find it not good, and related to performance, I want to search for other ways to simplify code and easier to understand.

exp code:
`if(array.length === 1){loop array[0].values}`

`if(array.length === 2){loop array[0].values { loop array[1].values }}`

`if(array.length === 3){loop array[0].values { loop array[1].values { loop array[2].values } }}`

the number of objects is not fixed, so check if other inconveniences ...

Comment: Sorry, I brought the problem to the wrong question, I updated it

Comment: @JaromandaX I write an example for js iteration, the problem I want to solve is the number of objects in the array is not fixed, how to properly check and iterate those objects

Comment: I'm not good at English, and bad at presenting, the problem I'm having a bit of trouble and is related to the business, I'll try to find a solution, thank you for taking the time for me.

Answer (score 1):

All you need are three basic nested loops and just push the values onto a new array

```js
const array_one = ["a", "b", "c"];
const array_two = ["d", "e"];
const array_three = ["f", "g", "h"];

const final_array = []

let c = 0;
for (let one of array_one) {
  for (let two of array_two) {
    for (let three of array_three) {
      final_array.push({[`exp${++c}`]:one, [`exp${++c}`]:two, [`exp${++c}`]:three})
    }
  }
}

console.log(final_array)
```

Comment: The number of arrays is dynamic, there may be 1, 2 3 or 4 arrays or more, I am using the same method as you, and have to check the number of existing arrays, I want to find some easier way.

Comment: I gave the example incorrectly, I corrected it a bit.